# create row but promise not resolve

Tags: sequelize.js, chai, chai-as-promised

Using seqalizerjs, resolve a promise:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            return models.merchants.create({
                name: ctx.name,
            });
        }).then(function(result){
            resolve({
                id: result.id
            });
        }).catch(function(err){
            reject(err);
        });
```

testing with chai as promise

```
return user.save(data).should.eventually.equal('123123');
```

but I always get this:

```
 Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure
 it resolves.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies in this line:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        return models.merchants.create({
            name: ctx.name,
        });
        // .....
```

a `Promise` function should has `resolve()`, something like this:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve(models.merchants.create({
            name: ctx.name,
        }));
```

Based on [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/id/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise):

> The resolve and reject functions are bound to the promise and calling them fulfills or rejects the promise, respectively.

Still based on the reference, there is the `Promise` flow graph:
[image]

The `then()` or `catch()` after `Promise()` doesn't handle the `resolve()` nor `reject()`, they only handle the value passed from either `resolve()` or `reject()`.

So, I think your code should be something like this:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    resolve(models.merchants.create({
        name: ctx.name,
    }));
}).then(function(merchants){
    console.log(merchants) // the created `merchants` from the `resolve()` of the promise would be passed here.
    return merchants;
});
```

**UPDATE**

Your code should look like this:

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    models.merchants.create({ // assuming `models.merchants.create()` is an async method
        name: ctx.name,
    }).then(function(result){
        resolve({
            id: result.id
        });
    }).catch(function(err){
        reject(err);
});
```

Comment: but now the problem is ReferenceError: reject is not defined

Comment: you should also removed the `reject()` in your `catch()`. You should use `reject()` in your `Promise()`